# how to get linux patch util to use env var in patch file

Tags: linux, git, patch, rpm

I am using omnibus to build a cli package, in which I have a patch I use to inject a few things into a file.
The patch itself is a git diff.
I want to use an environment variable as part of the content.
Something like:

```
diff --git a/cli/common.py b/cli/common.py
index 3eb3efd..1feae45 100644
--- a/cli/common.py
+++ b/cli/common.py
@@ -72,8 +72,12 @@

+++  - {'OLDPATH': 'NEWPATH/%{ENVVAR}}'
```

this is the syntax used when we were building with rpm.
It doesn't seem to work anymore, and i am certain that ENVVAR is set because it is successfully used in other parts of the packager script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `patch` program does not know anything about RPM variables.  You *could* run `patch` in an RPM spec-file using the diff-file as a here-document, which would attempt to substitute values in the script.  It might look like this:

```
patch <<EOF
index 3eb3efd..1feae45 100644
--- a/cli/common.py
+++ b/cli/common.py
@@ -72,8 +72,12 @@

+++  - {'OLDPATH': 'NEWPATH/%{ENVVAR}}'
EOF
```

An RPM will only substitute variables in its scriptlets, not in separate files.

Further reading:

- [Environment variables in RPM installation scripts](http://rpm-list.redhat.narkive.com/Qu0E6i5w/environment-variables-in-rpm-installation-scripts)